# Is there a tool to receive email via a REST (or similar) interface?

Tags: rest, email

I would like to add the ability to control an application via email. We already have a REST interface on the various components to allow them to communicate amongst each other (they are possibly spread across many machines). Is there some existing daemon that would listen to an SMTP interface and on receipt of a message, shunt it to a REST interface? (each part exists separately in python, for instance). It wouldn't be too difficult to merge the two, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists.